# How to draw 2 axes x,y in threejs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draw, threejs-editor

In threejs we have AxesHelper to draw 3 axes x,y,z. Now i want to draw 2 axes x,y , so in threejs is there any method to support this.
Thank your.

Comment: This sounds like a question for "did you search the web and maybe read through the rest of the Three.js docs?". Because maybe you did, but then [you want to mention that](/help/how-to-ask). And if you didn't: SO is your last resort, not your first =)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.